# how to update table on the basis of other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called queue_status which has three columns

```
1. id
2. queueanme
3. description
```

and one more table mail_sent which has four columns

```
1.Id
2.DocNo.
3.Emailid
4.Email_sent
```

I want to increase the email_sent count every time by 1. and upto 90 when queuename contains value 'test'.

thanks

Comment: provide sample data and expected results

Comment: Please show a relationship between the tables if any. Also give us what data you have to show, and what you expect the results to be.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with sidux that more information would be helpful here.  If you really want to update mail_sent when queue_status is updated, you have a few options.  One, you can centralize the code that adds/updates/deletes from the queue_status update.  This will give you one area that modifies the queue_status data and give you the ability to update mail_sent accordingly.  This can either be done through whatever language/technology you're using or in the database using a stored procedure to update queue_status.

Another option if you need mail_sent updated based on queue_status and yo have no control over what all might update queue_status is to add a trigger to queue_status.  A proper trigger can see what is being added/updated/deleted and would allow you to update mail_sent accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are relating the mail_sent table to the queue_status table yet. You probably should give us some more sample data to work with.

If you are looking for a count of occurrences in the 'queueanme' column to insert into your mail_sent table, then you could do something like this. Until we get more data, my answer is only a guess at what you are needing.

```
DECLARE @queue_status TABLE
(
   id varchar(32),
   queueanme varchar(max),
   [description] varchar(200)
)

DECLARE @mail_sent TABLE
(
   Id varchar(32),
   DocNo int,
   Emailid varchar(32),
   Email_sent int
)

INSERT INTO @queue_status
VALUES(REPLACE(NEWID(),'-',''), 'test', 'Record 1'), 
    (REPLACE(NEWID(),'-',''), 'test, Test', 'Record 2'), 
    (REPLACE(NEWID(),'-',''), 'test, test, Test test blah blah blah Test', 'Record 3')

SELECT *, (LEN(queueanme) - LEN(REPLACE(queueanme, 'test', ''))) / LEN('test')
FROM @queue_status
```